# What's the difference between a simple and 1-foliolate (unifoliolate) leaf?

Tags: botany, terminology, plant-anatomy, morphology

How is a 1-foliolate leaf (e.g., *Hardenbergia*) different from a simple leaf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Short answer:

Look for a pulvinus at the leaf-stalk/leaf-lamina junction.

[image]

---

#### Long Answer:

So from a strictly anatomical identification standpoint, this can be a bit confusing.

According to "[Plant Identification Terminology: An Illustrated Glossary](http://lib.du.ac.ir/documents/10157/60743/Plant+Identification+Terminology+Glossary.pdf)" (Harris & Harris, 2001):

> **Simple**: Undivided, as a leaf blade which is not separated into leaflets.

Where:

> **Leaflet**: A division of a compound leaf

and

> **Compound Leaf**: A leaf separated  into two or more distinct leaflets.

So the definition of a compound leaf is to have "two or more distinct" leaflets.

But wait...

From [plantnet](http://plantnet.rbgsyd.nsw.gov.au/cgi-bin/NSWfl.pl?page=nswfl&glossary=yes&term=one-foliolate&ill=Fig.+3+I):

> one-foliolate (1-foliolate, unifoliolate): a compound leaf reduced to a single leaflet, usually recognized by the articulated or jointed ‘petiole’, which is in fact a petiole plus a petiolule.

So what gives?

Perhaps this is due to a deficiency in terminology, as discussed (and corrected) by [Jiménez-Saa 2011](https://projects.ncsu.edu/cals/plantbiology/ncsc/vulpia/pdf/2011_Jimenez_terminology.pdf).

But, again Harris & Harris (2001) hint toward how this might arise [emphasis mine]:

> **Unifoliolate**: a leaf *theoretically* compound, though only expressing as a single leaflet and appearing simple.

So there is *still* a fundamental difference between the two.

Structurally, we can see the difference at the basal joint of the foliar structure:

> Simple or unifoliolate: The leaf is undivided...**with (unifoliolate)** or without (simple) **an articulation between the leaf lamina and leaf stalk**. [[source](https://www.anbg.gov.au/cpbr/cd-keys/peakey/key/The%20Pea%20Key/Media/Html/33_leaf_type.html)]

[Put differently](http://www.cactus-art.biz/note-book/Dictionary/Dictionary_U/dictionary_unifoliolate_leaf.htm):

> Unifoliolate leaf is usually **recognized from a simple leaf by the presence of a distinct joint or a pulvinus at the lamina-petiole junction**, which is in fact a petiole plus a petiolule.

- Note: **Pulvinus** = a distinct enlargement/swelling at the base of (sometimes at the apex of) a petiole or of a petiolule.

---

Note: a discussion about the developmental evolution of unifoliolate characteristics in *Cercis canadensis* is discussed [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2174894/).